# Resize Ubuntu /dev/sda1 partition in vmware

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization

I recently started using an appliance vm, I noticed that the `/dev/sda1` partition has about 55% already. I changed the size of the virtual hard disk from 10gig to 100gig so I'm looking to expand the partition `/dev/sda1` using the `/dev/sda3`

I tried to run a `resize2fs /dev/sda1` but the result was

```
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem is already 11718400 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Here is the info from the server

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-131-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


Last login: Mon Jul 30 23:44:23 2018
root@appliance:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe0e421e7

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048  16383966  16381919  7.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       16384000 209715199 193331200 92.2G 8e Linux LVM
root@opsview-appliance:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           396M   23M  373M   6% /run
/dev/sda1       7.6G  4.1G  3.5G  55% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/0
root@appliance:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `/` isn't using LVM, so your approach of creating an additional partition and use it as an LVM PV doesn't work.

Assuming that `/dev/sda3` is really empty, you need to

- delete `/dev/sda3`
- resize the partition  `/dev/sda1` to use all space. This step is important. You can use `parted` to do this, as an example.
- `resize2fs` the filesystem on `/dev/sda1` (this assumes  you are using ext3/4 as filesystem, not e.g. XFS

Before you do any of this, make sure you have a working backup.

Comment: Okay I deleted the sda3 and rebooted. When I tried to do the resize2fs /dev/sda1 I the following                                                                                                            resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem is already 11718400 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

Comment: a) Don't post error messages in comments. b) Read my answer. You have omitted the `resize the partition` step. This is something else then resizing the file system.

Comment: Your response makes no sense. I tried to resize the /dev/sda1 and it failed, i'm new to this sort of operation so i'm asking for what else can I try.

Comment: @FullStack It makes perfect sense.  You tried to resize the filesystem.  A file system lives on a partition.  Your partition hasn't changed sizes.  Therefore your resize of the filesystem fails because it's already filling up the partition.

Comment: @FullStack: This site is for professional system administrators, so you really should understand what "resize a partition" means. This is *very* basic knowledge, that is also extremely easy to search for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go deep into details, you can boot your VM from GParted live ISO (https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/) and change(expand, resize, etc) your partitions with GParted GUI tool.